# NextJS app-dir global-error not catching error in layout

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to make use of the new NextJS 13 `error.js` [error-handling file conventions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/error) for app-dir based apps. Fortunately, I've made some changes recently which have introduced a bunch of errors, so I can test this :)

In the `/app` dir I've created both an `error.js` and a `global-error.js`. My understanding is, the latter is the super-fallback, for if you have errors in your `/app/layout.js`.

If I go to my root page, `localhost:3000/`, I'm currently getting an error on the client:

```
Warning: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.
Toaster
TrackProvider
Providers
div
body
html
Component@
RedirectBoundary
Component@
NotFoundBoundary
DevRootNotFoundBoundary
PureComponent@
HotReload
Router
Component@
ErrorBoundary
AppRouter
ServerRoot
RSCComponent
Root
PureComponent@
```

The actual error seems to be caused because of the async/await I've added to my `Toaster` component to optimise loading:

```
export const Toaster = async (props) => {
    const {
        Toast,
        ToastCloseTrigger,
        ToastDescription,
        ToastGroup,
        ToastPlacements,
        ToastProvider,
        ToastTitle
    } = (await import('@ark-ui/react'));
...
```

**The question is, why isn't that caught by `global-error.js`?**

Here's my `/app/global-error.js` (I've simplified it down, to make sure it wasn't causing the errors, but left the original intent in as comments):

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';

// import '@/global.css';
// import { FontMerriweather, FontRoboto } from '@/styles/font';
// import { Heading } from '@/components/atoms/Heading';

export default function Error({ error, reset }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // TODO: Log error to reporting service
        console.error(error);
    }, [error]);

    return (
        // <html lang='en' className={`${FontMerriweather.variable} ${FontRoboto.variable}`}>
        <html lang='en' >
            <body>
                {/* <Heading> */}
                <h2>
                    Something went wrong globally!
                </h2>
                {/* </Heading> */}
                <button onClick={reset}>
                    Try Again
                </button>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

I believe I can fix the error fairly easily, but why isn't it being caught?

The original `Toaster` causing the error is from `Provider` in my global layout:

```
// /app/layout.js
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang='en' className={`${FontMerriweather.variable} ${FontRoboto.variable}`}>
            <body>
                <Flex direction={'column'} minH={'100vh'} pos={'relative'}>
                    <Providers>
                        ...
                    </Providers>
                </Flex>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

// /app/Provider.js
'use client';

import { Toaster } from '@/components/molecules/Toaster';
import TrackProvider from '@/utils/trackProvider';

function Providers({children}) {
    return (
        <TrackProvider>
            <Toaster>
                {children}
            </Toaster>
        </TrackProvider>
    )
}

export default Providers;
```